# Haskell Cryptonite HMAC SHA To JSON

Tags: haskell, cryptography, sha

While learning haskell, I gave myself the challenge to create an SHA HMAC and return it as a Text.

I got it finally working.
I was wondering though if there is a nicer way to write what I did. I am using [cryptonite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite). The `text` function in my examples comes from the Spock Webframework and returns finally a json output to the browser. 
My question is more about everything after `json`. Can I make this shorter? Nicer to read? Or maybe you are thinking: Why is he not using the soandso package?
I am new to the environement, so if you have any suggestion to make my line nicer or for using a different package, pleas let me know.

Here is what I did:

```
import Crypto.MAC.HMAC
import Crypto.Hash.Algorithms
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Text (pack )

app :: SpockM Connection AppSession AppState ()
app = do 
    get ("json/id") $ do
        json . pack $ show $ (hmacGetDigest $ (hmac ("MySecret"::B.ByteString) ("Somethin To Hash"::B.ByteString) ::HMAC SHA256))
```

Comment: What don't you like about it? Aside from the type annotations (some of which I imagine you might not need in some real context) this seems fine to me.

Comment: Exactly the type annotation I don't like, but the compiler had some problems  with the B.ByteStrings and asked me to clarify  the  types. Thanks for confirming what I did

Comment: Yep, so where they can't be inferred (like when you compose a polymorphic function like `show` with a function with a polymorphic result type) you'll need type annotations. You might factor out some part of that line into a top-level function `hmacSH256` just to fix its type signature if you intend to use it elsewhere, or just split the line into several `let` declarations in that `do` block. Any of those would be idiomatic.